Java Script - Erro de referência não detectado: $ não está definido
Boa tarde! Tudo bem? Sou novo por aqui, preciso de uma ajuda de vcs! Oque acontece que eu estava criando um formulário de validação de email com java script, no VSCode não acusou nenhum erro aparente mas na hora teste e homologação digitava um e-mail e clicava em validar não apareceu a confirmação no Google Chrome mas quando aperto o "F12" na parte de "Depuração" tinha um erro que é esse: "Uncaught Reference Error: $ is not defined"!
HTML:

<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test-jogo da velha em React</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Este é um projeto de teste</p>
    <script src="email.js"></script>
    <form>
        <p>Enter an email address:</p>
        <input id='email'>
        <button type='submit' id='validate'>Validate!</button>
        <h2 id='result'></h2>
        </form>
</body>
</html>

JS:
    function validateEmailAddress(email) {
        var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(email);
        }
        function validate() {
        $("#result").text("");
        var emailaddress = $("#email").val();
        if (validateEmailAddress(emailaddress)) {
        $("#result").text(emailaddress + " is valid :)");
        $("#result").css("color", "green");
        } else {
        $("#result").text(emailaddress + " is not correct, please retry:(");
        $("#result").css("color", "red");
        }
        return false;
        }
        $("#validate").bind("click", validate);

Então alguém consegue me ajudar por favor? humildemente! Muito Obrigado!!


O primeiro passo é [edit] trocando os prints de tela e trecho solto de código por um [mcve] do problema. Ao editar, a pergunta automaticamente é destacada para que a comunidade possa reavaliar. O que já dá pra adiantar é que $ não é uma sintaxe de JavaScript, provavelmente você copiou o código de algum lugar que usa alguma biblioteca que definiu $ previamente (tem várias que fazem isso).

A conversa ficou extensa nos comentários e foi convertida em um chat - é possível prosseguir com o diálogo utilizando o link passado.
